# Using data returned from AjaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get access to the data returned from an ajaxSubmit request.

```
 $("#searchbutton").on('click', function() {
            $("#searchform").ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(data) {
                    populate('#registrationform', data);
                },
                resetForm: true
            });
        });
```

The data that is returned is not being recognise by my populate function, If i do however with raw data,

```
 $("#searchbutton").on('click', function() {
            $("#searchform").ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(data) {
                    populate('#registrationform', {studentId: 1, firstName: 'Kay'});
                },
                resetForm: true
            });
        });
```

my populate function works. Any ideas why the data returned is not recognised?

Comment: Maybe the `data` is returned in a different format than expected? Like for instance it returns an array containing the object?

Comment: You could add a `console.log(data)` in your success callback and see what is being returned. Either that, or just inspect the response using firebug/dev console/fiddler.

Comment: the data returned is in that exact format.

Comment: problem still exist. the data that is returned is exactly what is hard coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the data is actually coming back as a String, NOT a JavaScript object.  If you are inspecting with `console.log(data)`, this distinction would be very easy to miss.

Looking at the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) for the `success` method and the `dataType` option, it is quite possible that your server's response is being taken for a simple String.  Try explicitly setting `dataType: "json"` and see what comes back.  That, or deserialize to an object with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: What do you get when you try the following?

`
    success: function(data) {
       console.log(typeof data);
       var obj = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(typeof obj);
       populate('#registrationform', obj);
    }
`

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}',         Response: {studentId: 1, firstName:'Dave'}.                        JSon: studentId 1, firstName  Dave

Comment: Hmm.. so did `console.log(typeof data)` yield `object`?  My suspicion was `String`.  It looks from the JSON.parse error like it may be that your response coming back is not valid JSON.  Specifically, you may have forgotten to put quotation marks around your keys.  I do this all the time.  I.e. instead of `{studentId: 1, firstName:'Dave'}` you should have `{"studentId": 1, "firstName":"Dave"}`.

Comment: it didn't yield object, it did said string.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brettjonesdev. After all i was not creating a proper JSON and also not parsing back string to JSON. It works well now. Thanks

Comment: Fantastic!  I can't tell you how many times I've done the *exact same thing*.  Such a pain!  Never can seem to remember that JS object !== JSON format.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like,

```
$("#searchbutton").on('click', function() {
     $("#searchform").ajaxSubmit({
         success: function(data) {// data should be return as json
            populate('#registrationform',{studentId: data.id, firstName: data.name});
         },
         resetForm: true
     });
});
```

Comment: The data is already coming in that format. why do I need to rewrite the string of data?